# Getting an error when trying to run a .py file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started learning the very basics of Python today, and I thought I'd download the extension for it in Visual Studio Code (I have also downloaded Python from Python.org).

I ran a simple *Hello, World!* code on the inbuilt terminal just fine, but then I attempted to write it into a function and call that function to print through an `if` statement. I was copying a video on Linkedinlearning so it should be legitimate, but alas when I went to run it I got a string of errors and none of the googling I have done has found me a solution for this problem. Even when I removed the function the normal *Hello, World!* will not work, e.g.

Please if you have any suggestions please let me know.
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extensions and other similar ones, but to no avail.

Here are the inputs and errors in text

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

> & C:/Users/euanr/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Python/Helloworld.py
> Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

> Current thread 0x000026c4 (most recent call first):
> PS C:\Python> Unable to initialize device PRN

Comment: [edit] and post the errors here (as text - not an image).

Comment: i've edited it now

Comment: [Fatal Python error on Windows 10 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'](//stackoverflow.com/a/51911598)